# How to identify an encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption

I have found a small encryption in a programm and would like to identify it, in terms of the public name. I have been programming with a DES and with TEA, but what i have here is not even similar with these.

The Algorithm is en/encrypting (exactly, only) 4 byte blocks, is using 5 steps left and right shifting, and xoring.  All calculations are crosswise combinations of the above,  no replacing "s-boxes" are involved.

I see a "seed" ? of 8 bytes , there is another 4 byte block involved, all encryption ends up in a 4 byte block for a 4 byte start. The encryptio. is done by executing 20 identical rounds with no other modification involved.

I would like to identify the algorithm to make my mind up about the security of this codepiece. It isnt very high anyway because of the small blocksize, which allows a brute force plaintext attack, but i am just interested about the background of this. If i had a closer find to all the available principle algorithm procedures, I would try to find the final match by myself, but as far as i looked into others i was lost by my missing general knowledge.

Update: I saw the answered question of a base64-lookings string (no information there was helpful for me) but i have a different case here.

I do not want to identify an encryption by the output string format, i want to identify it by parameters (functionalities used) of the algorithm i see in the code. I have added some more info in the desription of the parameters i found.
I am sure it is encryption (no hash) because its working both ways.

Thanks again for any support.

Comment: If you are trying to identify an algorithm based on its actual behavior, you may want to try Cryptography.SE.  I'm not sure if it is a good fit there or not, but it is more likely to fit there than here.